# Is there a way to get the value that the list contains which matched the values in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of words like this:

```
words1 = ['hi','my']
words2 = ['name','is']
```

and I have the Dataframe `df` like this:

```
id Sentence
0  'my name was'
1  'hi i am'
2  'my phone is'
3  'what is this'
4  'her name was'
```

and I am running the following code to get the index of Dataframe where values match.

```
matched_idx1 = df.loc[df.Sentence.str.contains('|'.join(words1)),:].index.array
matched_idx2 = df.loc[df.Sentence.str.contains('|'.join(words2)),:].index.array
```

Hence the `matched_idx1` gives the array:

```
[0,1,2]
```

and `matched_idx2` gives the array:

```
[0,2,3,4]
```

Now I want to get the list or array of values that matched in the contains function.

So for say a new variable `matched_idx1_values` the output should be:

```
['my','hi','my']
```

and for `matched_idx2_values` the output should be:

```
['name','is','is','name']
```

Please let me know how I can obtain these kind of indexes along with the values that they matched with. This example is very trivial, the lists I have have many more words.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `spaCy` library.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I will check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a full example of using spaCy:

```
# Sample data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}, 'Sentence': {0: 'my name was', 1: 'hi i am', 2: 'my phone is', 3: 'what is this', 4: 'her name was'}})


# Load spacy
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
ruler = nlp.add_pipe('entity_ruler', config={"overwrite_ents": True}, last=True)


# add word patterns
lst_all_patterns = list()

for wrd in words1:
    lst_all_patterns += [{"label": "words1", "pattern": [{"lower": wrd}]}]

for wrd in words2:
    lst_all_patterns += [{"label": "words1", "pattern": [{"lower": wrd}]}]

ruler.add_patterns(lst_all_patterns)


# EXAMPLE:
doc_string = nlp('my name was')
for e in doc_string.ents:
    print(e.label_, e, e.start, e.end)

# words1 my 0 1
# words1 name 1 2


# EXAMPLE dataframe
df['docs'] = df['Sentence'].map(nlp)
df['docs'].map(lambda x: [e.start for e in x.ents])

# 0    [0, 1]
# 1       [0]
# 2    [0, 2]
# 3       [1]
# 4       [1]
# Name: docs, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know if it works! Cheers.

Comment: Hey @Andreas in the EXAMPLE doc=nlp('my name was') for e in x.ents. I am getting an error which says x is not defined, however there is no error in the EXAMPLE dataframe.

Comment: Got it, it should be docs not e. No problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I figured out a way to do it using regex using re.compile('|'.join(words1)) then using for i in df['sentence'].values: findall(i). it seems easier and faster.

Comment: @ShouryaVerma, yes for single task it is propably easier, but if you want to do other natural language processing task down the road its easier to work with spaCy. However, if that one task is all you need then the regex solution is fine.